# No type named 'nullptr_t' in namespace 'std'

Tags: macos, qt, gcc, c++11

Someone is compiling my Qt program that is using the [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) standard and they got this error (Mac OS X / gcc). I know I can declare it, but shouldn't it be already in `<cstddef>`?

```
./collectable_smartptr.hpp:54:33: error: no type named 'nullptr_t' in namespace 'std'
void operator=(std::nullptr_t &null)
```

This code works just fine on Windows and Linux, I see it just on Mac.

Mac is i386-apple-darwin11.3.0, compiler is:

```
$ g++ --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0
Thread model: posix
```

g++ options (some) are `-c -pipe -std=c++11 -O2 -arch x86_64 -Xarch_x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -Wall -W -DQT_USE_QSTRINGBUILDER -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WEBKIT_LIB -DQT_XML_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED`

Is this normal? Or is there something extra what needs to be done on Mac for C++11 to work?

Comment: Did you `#include <cstddef>`?

Comment: do I have to? why it works on linux and windows if it's needed?

Comment: That is the header which contains the definition for that type. Maybe it happened to work because some other header included it for you on those platforms, but this is not required.

Comment: Just because your code happens to work while you depend on implementation specifics, doesn't mean that the code is correct. You have a bug. A bug that affects portability - demonstrably so. Fix it. That's all there's to it. For the future, you can look at [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) - for every standard class, it tells you what header you **must** include. Failing to include it doesn't mean it won't work on all platforms. It may work on some. It may even work but have subtle bugs that bite you later. You've been warned :)

Comment: MacOSX has had a fully compliant C++11 compiler for several years.  What nobody has yet pointed out, but that is highly obvious from the output above is that *you're not using GCC or its standard library* but rather `clang` and it's standard library implementation.  It is not entirely unknown for different implementations to include slightly different headers.   The fault lies with your program not including header files it needs - not with `clang`.

Comment: @KubaOber how can I fix the bug? When I include mentioned header it's still same, so which other header should I include then

Comment: @Petr: first try to give a reproduceable example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is always better to include things explicitly and so, I would add this to the code:

```
#include <cstddef>
```

If that does not work that means you have a fundamental issue with your system, namely:

- You do not use a recent enough standard library implementation (e.g. try libc++).
- You do not have the C++11 and on compilation enabled.

As a quick and nasty workaround, you could do the typedef yourself of course, as follows:

```
namespace std {
    typedef decltype(nullptr) nullptr_t;
}
```

or without `std`, but this really ought to be the last resort, and usually it means you are doing something wrong.

Comment: this doesn't work: error: no type named 'nullptr_t' in namespace 'std'

Comment: @Petr: update your libc++ implementation, or do `typedef decltype(nullptr) nullptr_t; ` on your own for Mac.

Comment: No, I posted code that helped to separate answer, I know it may not be correct answer in general, but maybe someone else who might face this problem might benefit from knowing it

Comment: indeed, I just didn't notice you wrote it here :P I found it in another post... but thanks

Answer (score 3):

Using `#include <cstddef>` didn't resolve the problem, but inserting

```
namespace std
{
    typedef decltype(nullptr) nullptr_t;
}
```

did apparently help get through this problem, despite I still don't understand why it was really needed.

PS: Given that I am not owner of computer where this happens I can't do any further investigation, see https://github.com/huggle/huggle3-qt-lx/issues/101 for details

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I included `sstream` in the namespace `std`:

```
namespace std {
// Some #ifdefs and so on
// quite hidden
#include <sstream>
}
```

Moving the include out of the namespace resolved the issue:

```
#include <sstream>
namespace std {
}
```

Compiler: Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38) without C++11.